# Find a file in directory where i know part of the filename and the extension

Tags: unix, find

I know the file im looking for begins with a data for example `20131111` and I know the file ends in `.log`, but I don't know the full file name,

what is a unix command that would allow me to see all files beginning with or containing this date and ending with `.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
find /certain/path -type f -name "20131111*.log"
```

- `-type f` - just files.
- `-name "20131111*.log"` files whose name starts with `20131111` and ends with `log`.